# Java Application Deploying With SQL Server Database

Tags: java, sql-server, swing, hibernate

I developed a java swing application by using hibernate connection and MS SQL server for database. Application is working fine. And I know the way to create and EXE and the installer for application.My question is, how I install this application to another computer with database. Should I install the SQL server on that computer or is there any way to use the db without installing the whole SQL server in that computer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is no way of using database without installing the SQL Server, unless you configure in a way that the application will communicate with the db on your pc, but that's complicated

Answer (score 0):

A different approach to this would be for you to make a view in the database and extract the data you need to a csv file, include that file in the resources folder of the application and then use `Lucene` to query over it

Take a look at how to get started:  [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/gettingstarted.html)

When you need to update the data in the file you can release updates for the application that would include these changes in the csv file/s